# Android: How to include mlpack c++ library into android project?

Tags: android, c++, android-native-library, mlpack

I trying to include [mlpack c++](https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack) library into my android project
but getting an error when using some function of mlpack like:

```
NeighborSearch<NearestNeighborSort, ManhattanDistance> nn(data);
```

**Error:**

```
> undefined reference to `mlpack::Log::Assert(bool, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&)'
> clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
> invocation) ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed
```

Could you please help me step by step to resolve this issue?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: I included mlpack, boost, and armadillo under src/main/cpp/include &
all files are now getting each other but the problem is the following error when trying to build the project:

D:/DummyProject/MlPackBuild/app/src/main/cpp/include\mlpack/core/tree/hrectbound_impl.hpp:230: undefined reference to `mlpack::Log::Assert(bool, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&)'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71122249/edit) this into the question, comments are poor for formatting

Comment: Have you linked to the mlpack libraries? Is mlpack compiled with the same standard library as your project?

Comment: Where need to link? I put it inside src/main/cpp/include/mlpack and linked it as :

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include) 

into CMakeLists.txt

Comment: you need to link to the library